# select records between two months with year difference

Tags: mysql, sql, select, between

I have a table which contain records of people according to month and year.
table have multiple columns in which there are two columns which are fldmonth & fldyear, which contain month no and year respectively.

Now I want to fetch data between months of different year. (E.g. 3-2012 to 6-2013)

I am using following query, but not getting proper record.

```
SELECT * FROM 'table' WHERE
user_id = 'id' AND
STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('fldyear', 'fldmonth', '01'), '%Y%m%d') BETWEEN
STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('2012', '3', '01'), '%Y%m%d') AND 
STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('2013', '6','01'), '%Y%m%d');
```

**Table Schema :**

```
user_id varchar(100), fldmonth smallint(2), fldyear mediumint(4)
```

(table name & userid given here are just for example)

Please need help.

**Note:** I used %c also in date format because month are in 1,2,..12 format. But still am getting empty result set

Comment: add a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) please

Comment: sorry, but data is sensitive. Please consider sample example.

Comment: What actually problem with this query?

Comment: post your table schema atleast, without the field names how can you expect as to help?

Comment: Really sorry. Yes but schema for columns are.. user_id varchar(100), fldmonth smallint(2), fldyear mediumint(4)

Comment: Create the output of some rows which you asking to show..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM tbl 
WHERE USERID=1 and
STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(fldyear,'-',LPAD(fldmonth,2,'00'),'-',LPAD(fldate,2,'00')), '%Y-%m-%d')
BETWEEN
STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(2012,'-',LPAD(03,2,'00'),'-',LPAD(01,2,'00')), '%Y-%m-%d') AND 
STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(2013,'-',LPAD(06,2,'00'),'-',LPAD(01,2,'00')), '%Y-%m-%d');
```

## [Working Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4a277/51)

Answer (score 1):

Remove `Single quote` from column names.

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE user_id = 'id' AND
      STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(fldyear, fldmonth, '01'), '%Y%c%d') BETWEEN '2012-03-01' AND '2013-06-01';
```

Comment: @Shri can you please post your table schema?

Comment: @Shri Saharsh Shah's is right but also have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/21374718/829533 .. actually you need to add `()` brackets with your conditions..

Comment: still getting empty result set.

Comment: can i use limit clause?

Answer (score 0):

Saharsh Shah is right, but what you need is to add brackets `()` too in your condition

change the condition with

```
WHERE user_id = 'id' AND
( STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(fldyear, fldmonth, '01'), '%Y%m%d')
BETWEEN '2012-03-01' AND '2013-06-30' );
```

Comment: Getting empty result set.